# rowHeight in cellForRowAtIndexPath unchanged

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a problem with rowHeight, which seems to be not changed ( though I do it in method heightForRow...)

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 80;
    } else
        return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    // Configure the cell...


    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        NSLog(@"frame.size.height: %f rowHeight: %f", cell.frame.size.height, tableView.rowHeight);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

It says 44.0000 for both values: cell.frame.size.height and for rowHeight.

Here's how do I initialize this table in navcontroller:

```
DPSettingsInformations *settingsInformations = [[DPSettingsInformations alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsInformations animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

44 is the default height so it sounds as if you haven't set the `UITableViewDelegate`.

`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` requires the `UITableViewDelegate` to be set.  Make sure that this is set correctly in the Nib, Storyboard or in code. Usually you set it at the same time as the `UITableViewDataSource`.

Example (if setting in code):

```
// UITableViewDataSource delegate
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
// UITableViewDelegate delegate
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```